When I add DaisyUI to my base.html in development, dark mode gets inherited into form fields - but how can I disable this?
I am building a Django app and am using Tailwind and DaisyUI for styling. I built my app in light mode and would like for all users (even those whose systems are set to dark mode) to show light mode, because the rest of the website otherwise looks awful & the styles are too contrasting.
The problem is this - when I change my system to dark mode, form fields get set to a dark background, whereas the rest of the site has been designed to style in light mode and does not have an alternative theme (yet).
Because I am still in dev, I am importing both Daisy and Tailwind via CDN. I am certain that the addition of Daisy is causing this problem, because when I go 1 commit before the addition of Daisy, this problem does not occur. What is interesting however, is that this background colour change is happening even to fields that have not yet been specified as Daisy input fields.
As mentioned, removal of the Daisy import solves this issue (but this obviously isn't ideal!). I have tried going to my tailwind config and performing the following, all individually at different times:
daisyui: {    themes: false, }
then I tried
daisyui: {      themes: ["light"],   }
then I tried
daisyui: {      themes: [],   }
then I tried
daisyui: {      base: false,   }
but none of these seem to work - the fields in question continue to inherit from the system theme (which is set to dark mode on my Mac to test this behaviour), instead of having a background of white.

The DaisyUI CDN is a static file. No Tailwind configuration would affect the content of the file. You could consider refactoring to compiling Tailwind and Daisy UI instead of using the CDN to customize the Daisy UI themes and thus remove the dark theming.

@Wongjn thanks for your help - so likely using Tailwind and DaisyUI via a build step would solve this?

Likely using Tailwind and Daisy UI via a build step would solve this.
